# Big Omega Notation (Finding C and n0)

Tags: function, runtime, big-o

I'm trying to find the n0 of a function with a big omega size of n^3 where c=2.25

() = 3^3 − 39^2 + 360 + 20. In order to prove that () is Ω(^3),
we need constants , 0 > 0 such that () ≥ ^3 for every  ≥ 0

If c=2.25, how do I find the smallest integer that satisfies n0?

Comment: is c=2.25 the c you have to use or is that one you found?

Comment: 2.25 if the c i have to use to find n0

Comment: 2.25 is* the c i have to use to find n0*